# How to interpret a declaration when you have a type(char) a pointer(*) and a const keyword?

Tags: c, pointers

I am aware of the following sequences :

1. `const char*` -  mutable pointer to an immutable character/strin
2. `char* const` - an immutable pointer but the contents of location at which it points are mutable.
3. `const char* const` - immutable pointer to an immutable character/string.
4. `char*`  - entirely permissive.

However are we supposed to interpret the following :

```
char const *
```

Is there a way to intuitively understand what 1 , 2 and the *"new one"* means - or we have to learn it by heart.

Comment: `char const *` == `const char *`

Comment: http://cdecl.org/ is a good resource for these types of problems. (though does not help with `char const *`)

Comment: remember to read a declaration starting from the right.. That give const pointer to char'.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is "read it backwards".   This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/10396) explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

it's equivalent to `const char *`